# Oxide caused by running a saucepan with aluminium handle through the dishwasher

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Having run a saucepan with an aluminium handle through the dishwasher, the handle is producing a dark grey dusty residue, which I assume is an oxide of aluminium. The dishwasher was run with a typical dishwashing detergent as well as some drying agent (potentially).

The residue can be scoured off, leaving the shiny aluminium below. Having been scoured, the oxide doesn't seem to return.

What reaction is responsible for this? Obviously the high temperatures of the dishwasher is one factor, but what are the others?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think its oxide, as aluminium has a white oxide

Comment: @HahaHahaha **pure** aluminium oxide is white in colour - Most probably the compound is aluminium oxide with some other impurities, giving it a grey colour. It could also be sodium aluminate, as most dish washing liquids contain sodium Lauryl sulphate or some sodium based foaming agent

Comment: Aluminium used for cooking plate is not pure aluminium. It is an alloy, which contains Manganese, Silicium or other metals. If aluminium is oxidized, the impurities will not be oxidized and remain in the aluminium oxide layer. This makes a grey color.

Comment: @Andrew, aluminum (well, the Al2O3 coat) is attacked by *alkali* much more quickly than by most acids (except HF). Machine dish-washing detergents are highly *alkaline*, containing alkali metal carbonates and hypochlorites to saponify fats.

Comment: Hypochlorites are added to remove food stains/sterilize rather than to saponify fats. Hypochlorite is such a bad choice anyway due to its corrosive nature on heating elements and metals. Hope they are completely replaced by oxygen bleaches.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - HF does not attack Al2O3 particularly well, requiring a boiling HF solution to make much of a dent. I can leave a piece of sapphire in room-temperature HF all day long without noticing anything happening.

Comment: @JonCuster, the thin, somewhat porous layer of Al2O3 on aluminum exposed to air *is* attacked much more rapidly... though I admittedly don't work much with nasty HF. https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2004/03/03/things_i_wont_touch_1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dishwashers are corrosive to aluminum?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34152/why-dishwashers-are-corrosive-to-aluminum)